# Reversing TranslateTransition on command

Tags: javafx-8

I am trying to do a TranslateTransition on Left Node of BorderPane. I can get the node to 'slide in' on click but 'slide out' is not working as expected. Here is the code snippet.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    vbx_lfpane.setVisible(false);
}    

@FXML
private void paneClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    if(vbx_lfpane.isVisible()) {
        vbx_lfpane.setVisible(false);
        TranslateTransition tt1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(500), vbx_lfpane);
        tt1.setFromX(vbx_lfpane.getLayoutBounds().getMinX());
        tt1.setToX( - (vbx_lfpane.getLayoutBounds().getMinX() + vbx_lfpane.getWidth()));
        tt1.play();
    } else {
        vbx_lfpane.setVisible(true);
        vbx_lfpane.setTranslateX(-vbx_lfpane.getWidth());
        TranslateTransition tt2 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(500), vbx_lfpane);
        tt2.setByX(vbx_lfpane.getWidth());
        tt2.play();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the visibility of `vbx_lfpane` to `false` before you start the "slide out" transition. You need to set the visibility to `false` when the transition is complete:

```
tt1.setOnFinished(e -> vbx_lfpane.setVisible(false));
tt1.play();
```